# I need to create a program that prints MY initials always no matter the size

Tags: java, arrays

Create an array and ask for the say of it and the character to be used to fill the array.
So it always needs to somehow resemble the two initials of my name, no matter the size.

```
        Example:    My name is Johann Pasquel => JP    
        Size of array: 5
        Character to be used : *

        *****   *****      
          *     *   *      
          *     *****      
          *     *                   
        ***     *
```

/*So far that , I have tried to do it "manually", just to say the first line of J should be always full.
sorry for my english,english is not my mothertongue*/

```
public class Array2Iniciales {
    public void incialesletras(int tamaño,char caracter){
        char[][] letraJ = new char[tamaño][tamaño];
        char[][] letraP = new char[tamaño][tamaño];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * tamaño - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(letraJ[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("  ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * tamaño - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(letraP[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What I think you're asking for is not simple.  Even creating one English alphabet letter, like J, in a multitude of sizes is not trivial.  One general approach would probably be to create a `BufferedImage` of the initials, then create a raster of the `BufferedImage` pixels and print the raster using the specified character.

Comment: *not simple*. Worse - it's not possible ;) What if the size were 1? See Unix 'banner' and 'figlet'

Answer (score 1):

Off hand, there are at least two ways you can possibly do this. Create your own alphabet within a 2D Array (or several 2D Arrays for different sizes of letters) or, as already mentioned in comments, create a **BufferedImage** of the initials, then create a raster of the **BufferedImage** pixels and print the raster using the specified character (in your case, the asterisk). Creating a **BufferedImage** allows you to actually set a Font and Font Size which can change the look of the characters printed to the Console Window.

**Create your own Alphabet** (read comments in code):

```
/* Create the Alphabet (in upper case) within a 2D Array:
   This alphabet is 5 characters wide by 5 characters deep 
   with the exception of the `W` which is 7 characters wide
   by 5 characters deep. The `J` is also off a little as it
   is 6 characters wide by 5 characters deep. Of course the 
   alphabet can be modified to whatever you like. 
*/
String[][] letters5x5 = {
    // A
    {"  *  ",
     " * * ",
     "*****",
     "*   *",
     "*   *"
    },
    // B
    {"**** ",
     "*   *",
     "**** ",
     "*   *",
     "**** "
    },
    // C
    {" *** ",
     "*   *",
     "*    ",
     "*   *",
     " *** "
    },
    // D
    {"**** ",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     "**** "   
    },
    // E
    {"*****",
     "*    ",
     "***  ",
     "*    ",
     "*****"   
    },
    // F
    {"*****",
     "*    ",
     "***  ",
     "*    ",
     "*    "   
    },
    // G
    {" ****",
     "*    ",
     "* ***",
     "*   *",
     " *** "
    },
    // H
    {"*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*****",
     "*   *",
     "*   *"   
    },
    // I
    {"*****",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  ",
     "*****"   
    },
    // J
    {" *****",
     "   *  ",
     "   *  ",
     "*  *  ",
     "****  "   
    },
    // K
    {"*   *",
     "* *  ",
     "**   ",
     "* *  ",
     "*   *"   
    },
    // L
    {"*    ",
     "*    ",
     "*    ",
     "*    ",
     "*****"   
    },   
    // M
    {"*   *",
     "** **",
     "* * *",
     "*   *",
     "*   *"   
    },   
    // N
    {"*   *",
     "**  *",
     "* * *",
     "*  **",
     "*   *"   
    }, 
    // O
    {" *** ",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     " *** "
    },
    // P
    {"**** ",
     "*   *",
     "**** ",
     "*    ",
     "*    "
    },
    // Q
    {" *** ",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     " *** ",
     "    *"
    },
    // R
    {"**** ",
     "*   *",
     "**** ",
     "* *  ",
     "*   *"
    },
    // S
    {" ****",
     "*    ",
     " *** ",
     "    *",
     "**** "
    },
    // T
    {"*****",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  "
    },
    // U
    {"*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*****"
    },
    // V
    {"*   *",
     "*   *",
     "*   *",
     " * * ",
     "  *  "
    },
    // W
    {"*     *",
     "*     *",
     "*  *  *",
     " * * * ",
     "  * *  "
    },
    // X
    {"*   *",
     " * * ",
     "  *  ",
     " * * ",
     "*   *"
    },
    // Y
    {"*   *",
     " * * ",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  ",
     "  *  "
    },
    // Z
    {"*****",
     "   * ",
     "  *  ",
     " *   ",
     "*****"
    },
};
    
// Open a keyboard input stream:
java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String ls = System.lineSeparator();  // System's newline character sequence:
    
// Get User's FULL Name (First (middle?) Last):
String name = "";
while (name.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your name (q to quit): -> ");
    name = userInput.nextLine().trim();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Quiting - Bye Bye!");
        return;
    }
    else if (name.replaceAll("(?i)[a-z ]", "").length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Name Entry (" + name + ")! "
                + "Only alphabetic characters! Try agsin..." + ls);
        name = "";
    }
}
    
/* Abbreviate the supplied User Name to character 
   initials (in upper case):        */
name = abbreviateName(name);
  
// Determine the letters required from `letters` array:
String[] abbrevParts = name.split("");
String[][] neededArtLetters = new String[abbrevParts.length][];
int lettersIndexValue;
for (int i = 0; i < abbrevParts.length; i++) {
    lettersIndexValue = abbrevParts[i].charAt(0) - 65;
    neededArtLetters[i] = Arrays.copyOf(letters5x5[lettersIndexValue], 
                                letters5x5[lettersIndexValue].length);
}
    
/* Print the determined letters from the `letters` 2D
   array (now contained within the `neededArtLetters`
   2D Array) to the Console Window. A nested `for`
   loop is required for this but first, we make sure
   the `neededArtLetters` 2D array actually contains 
   something otherwise, nothing gets printed:      */
if(neededArtLetters.length > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < neededArtLetters[0].length; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < neededArtLetters.length; j++){
            System.out.print(neededArtLetters[j][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
// Done!
```

**The `abbreviateName()` Method:**

```
/**
 * Abbreviates a full name (or String) to upper case initials.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param nameString (String) The full name (or string) to abbreviate.<br>
 * 
 * @param characterbetweenLetters (Optional - String varArg) The desired 
 * character to be added after each initial character. Usually this would 
 * be either a period or whitespace, but can be anything or nothing at all.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) An abbreviated version of the supplied `nameString` 
 * argument.
 */
public static String abbreviateName(String nameString, String... characterbetweenLetters) {
    if (nameString == null || nameString.isEmpty()) {
        return nameString;
    }
    String characterString = "";
    if (characterbetweenLetters.length > 0) {
        characterString = characterbetweenLetters[0];
    }
    return java.util.Arrays.stream(nameString.split("\\s+"))
            .map(t -> t.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
            .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(characterString));
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
Please enter your name (q to quit): -> Fred Flintstone
***** ***** 
*     *     
***   ***   
*     *     
*     *
```

---

**Using BufferedImage:**

```
/**
 * This method will take the supplied text and generate a ASCII Art banner
 * of that text and place it into a String[] Array. Once the Array is
 * returned you can iterate through it and save the contents to a text file
 * or display it within a Console Window.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
 *  {@code 
 *   Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 24);
 *      String text = "Hello World";
 *      String[] s  = stringToConsoleBanner(text, font, "*");
 *      for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
 *          System.out.println(s[i]);
 *      }
 *  }</pre>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string you want to convert to Banner text.<br>
 *
 * @param font (Font) The font you want your ASCII text to look like.<br>
 *
 * @param fromCharacter (String) The character you want to use for pixels.<br>
 *
 * @return (String[] Array)
 */
public static String[] stringToConsoleBanner(String inputString, java.awt.Font font, String fromCharacter) {
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = 
            new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(144, 32, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    java.awt.Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    
    /* If the supplied Font argument is null then the default font of 
       SansSerif will be used as Font.Plain and a size of 24!      */
    g.setFont(font == null ? new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 24) : font);
    java.awt.Graphics2D graphics = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
    graphics.setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                                java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics.drawString(inputString, 0, 24);

    java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int x = 0; x < 144; x++) {
            sb.append(image.getRGB(x, y) == -16777216 ? " " : 
                    image.getRGB(x, y) == -1 ? fromCharacter : fromCharacter);
        }
        if (sb.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }

        list.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

**Method Use:**

```
// Open a keyboard input stream:
java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String ls = System.lineSeparator();  // System's newline character sequence:
    
// Get User's FULL Name (First (middle?) Last):
String name = "";
while (name.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your name (q to quit): -> ");
    name = userInput.nextLine().trim();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Quiting - Bye Bye!");
        return;
    }
    else if (name.replaceAll("(?i)[a-z ]", "").length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Name Entry (" + name + ")! "
                + "Only alphabetic characters! Try agsin..." + ls);
        name = "";
    }
}
    
/* Abbreviate the supplied User Name to character 
   initials (in upper case):        */
name = abbreviateName(name);
  
java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font("Courior New", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 11);
String[] s = stringToConsoleBanner(name, font, "*");
for (String str : s) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
// Done!
```

See above for the `abbreviateName()` method.

**Console Output:**

```
Please enter your name (q to quit): -> Fred Flintstone
***** *****                                                                                                                                     
*     *                                                                                                                                         
*     *                                                                                                                                         
****  ****                                                                                                                                      
*     *                                                                                                                                         
*     *                                                                                                                                         
*     *                                                                                                                                         
*     *
```